# missing textures in linux

Tags: texturing, materials, linux

multi material on single object. materials can't be seen or display anomalies. this happens on all versions of blender after 2.8.2

[image: mb lab character. Multi material on one object]
[image: unknown]
[image: 2 textures here. missing face is simple colour (green)]

Comment: If it was working before and now it is not, then it could be a bug that needs to be reported.

Comment: whats the question?

Comment: the question is; does anyone have a solution to this problem?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution? I'm missing textures in premade tree models, also certain thumbnails aren't displayed in Blender, though the physical files are there and perfectly fine (Scatter 5 BagaPie biome). Nobody can explain it except pushing it off on Pop!OS.